# Calculation and comparison of objects in lists in the same position

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm having a problem, which I hope you can help me. In my project I have a virtual time that runs as soon as the script starts (24 virtual seconds in 1 real second). This time is recorded in a list and passed to the classes that need it from the main one. The list is made up of five elements [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], the first are the minutes, the second the hours, the third the days, the fourth the months and the fifth the years.

```
self.gTime = self.__engine.time
self.vTime = copy.deepcopy(self.gTime)
```

`gTime` is the general virtual time, while `vTime` is the variable time according to the events.

```
__grow = {
        "0": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "1": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "2": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "3": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "4": [10, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    }
```

This is a mini dictionary where there are five events that must happen. These events (the numbers inside are currently for testing), represent in simple words how much time must pass for that event to happen. Whenever that event occurs, `vTime` is updated with the value of `gTime` and the cycle continues for the next phase.

So I created this function:

```
def update_age(self):
    if self.__age <= len(self.__grow) - 1:
        for i, n in enumerate(self.gTime):
            if abs(self.gTime[i] - self.vTime[i]) == self.__grow[str(self.__age)][i]:
                self.vTime = copy.deepcopy(self.gTime)
                self.__age += 1
    else:
        pass
```

Where `age` determines which event should occur.

Now, if I start the script, I get this error:

```
if abs(self.gTime[i] - self.vTime[i]) == self.__grow[str(self.__age)][i]:
KeyError: '5'
```

Also, before the script ends in error, I can see that the sequence of events happens too quickly.

If instead I replace `self.__grow[str (self.__age)][i]` with for example 10, the script works correctly.

How should I change to get it working properly? Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Scrolling through time in the main class is generated like this:

```
self.__time = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
self.time = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def __time_update(self):
    time = datetime.now()
    if int(time.strftime("%S")) != self.__time[0]:
        self.__time[0] = copy.deepcopy(int(time.strftime("%S")))
        if self.__time[1] >= 60:
            self.__time[1] = self.__time[1] - 60
            self.__time[2] += 1
        if self.__time[2] >= 60:
            self.__time[2] = 0
            self.__time[3] += 1
        if self.__time[3] >= 24:
            self.__time[3] = 0
            self.__time[4] += 1
        if self.__time[4] >= 30:
            self.__time[4] = 0
            self.__time[5] += 1
        if self.__time[5] >= 4:
            self.__time[5] = 0
            self.__time[6] += 1

        self.__time[1] += 24

        if self.__time[2] % 10 == 0:
            self.time[0] = copy.deepcopy(self.__time[2])
        self.time[1] = copy.deepcopy(self.__time[3])
        self.time[2] = copy.deepcopy(self.__time[4])
        self.time[3] = copy.deepcopy(self.__time[5])
        self.time[4] = copy.deepcopy(self.__time[6])
```

`__time` every time you exit the script it is saved externally and reloaded when the script is started again.

The first part, for example, should simulate the growth of a tree (consisting of five phases) which must begin as soon as the entity is generated. Whenever `age` changes (and therefore a phase has taken place) the sprite is changed to the new one.

EDIT 2:

Unfortunately, the proposed solution, while solving the generated error, from a different type of problem: [Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jeQ.jpg)
In the first part, it's how you see it doing the suggested change. The second part in theory is how it should be (in test the change up to the final phase should happen every 10 minutes) that I got by replacing `self.__grow[str (self.__age)][i]` with for example 10. The last part is the error.

Either I change the way the virtual clock works, or I wouldn't know how to solve it sincerely...

EDIT 3:

At the end, I managed to solve by creating an external module:

```
from datetime import datetime
from copy import deepcopy

gTime = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
name_day = 0

__dt = 0
__s = 0
__m = 0
__h = 0
__dy = 0
__st = 0
__mh = 0
__y = 0

__local = "it"

__nDay = {
    "en": {
        "0": "Monday",
        "1": "Tuesday",
        "2": "Wednesday",
        "3": "Thursday",
        "4": "Friday",
        "5": "Saturday",
        "6": "Sunday"
    },
    "it": {
        "0": "Lunedì",
        "1": "Martedì",
        "2": "Mercoledì",
        "3": "Giovedì",
        "4": "Venerdì",
        "5": "Sabato",
        "6": "Domenica"
    },
}


def time_update():
    global __dt, __s, __m, __h, __dy, __st, __mh, __y, gTime, name_day

    vTime = datetime.now()
    if int(vTime.strftime("%S")) != __dt:
        __dt = deepcopy(int(vTime.strftime("%S")))
        if __s >= 60:
            __s = __s - 60
            __m += 1
        if __m >= 60:
            __m = 0
            __h += 1
        if __h >= 24:
            __h = 0
            __dy += 1
            __st += 1
        if __st >= 7:
            __st = 0
        if __dy >= 30:
            __dy = 0
            __mh += 1
        if __mh >= 4:
            __mh = 0
            __y += 1

        __s += 24

        if __m % 10 == 0:
            gTime[0] = deepcopy(__m)
        gTime[1] = deepcopy(__h)
        gTime[2] = deepcopy(__dy)
        gTime[3] = deepcopy(__mh)
        gTime[4] = deepcopy(__y)

        name_day = __nDay[__local][str(__st)]

def calculation_time(vList, cList):
    m = vList[0] + cList[0]
    h = vList[1] + cList[1]
    d = vList[2] + cList[2]
    ms = vList[3] + cList[3]
    y = vList[4] + cList[4]

    if m >= 60:
        h += 1
        m = 0
    if h >= 24:
        d += 1
        h = 0
    if d >= 30:
        ms += 1
        d = 0
    if ms >= 4:
        y += 1
        ms = 0

    if gTime[0] >= m:
        if gTime[1] >= h:
            if gTime[2] >= d:
                if gTime[3] >= ms:
                    if gTime[4] >= y:
                        return True
```

`time_update()` it is called by the main class every time it updates, while `calculation_time()` it is called by the individual entity classes that need to know the time to bring about a different behavior.

Thanks for everyone who replied and I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use actual `datetime.timedelta` objects?

Comment: I still don't quite understand what this is supposed to do, but are you maybe mixing up `str` and `int` keys, or one- and zero-based indices?

Comment: How should i do? This is because the cycle I use does not know if it is compatible in this sense. I don't know if it can help, but I can update the question by inserting how I get the flow of virtual time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```py
def update_age(self):
    if self.__age <= len(self.__grow) - 1:
        c=0
        for i, n in enumerate(self.gTime):
            if abs(self.gTime[i] - self.vTime[i]) >= self.__grow[str(self.__age)][i]:
                self.vTime = copy.deepcopy(self.gTime)
                c += 1
        if(c==i+1):
            self.__age += 1
    else:
        pass
```

From what you're saying - I would also drop `abs()`, but that's not relevant for the overall processing, just a simplification...

Comment: I edited the question to accommodate your solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hm, I edited my answer - I think the problem might be that you are validating whether *any* of `grow` coordinates matches, while you should check whether they all match.